# Microsoft Dynamics - Get events from an external source

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm looking for an ability to register data from an external system into Microsoft Dynamics CRM
For example, in Salesforce CRM there is 'Platform Event' which is used to get an event from an external source and trigger a UI change in accordance.

What's the equivalent in Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0):

To CRUD data in CRM:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-entity-web-api

To perform actions (the same stuff clicking buttons does) via API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/use-web-api-actions

Power Automate / Logic Apps has connectors for these out of the box if you prefer not to write code, they are billed by execution though.

Comment: Question - why not using MS Dynamics webhooks in order to send events from the external system into dynamics?

Comment: Yes, why not? :)